# rails object created from method or services class is not automatically initialised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am relatively new to Rails and trying to create an object from a model (I've also tried the same from a service I created in app/services/).

The object gets created, but fails when I access the page that tries to call a method on the object (I want to use .find(id) and I get a message about 'nil' method, because of this):

When I check the object in the console after the error of a nil method, the object has been created, but all the variable types are set to 'nil':

If I create a new object of the same class from the console, the object has variable that are typed:

Trans(id: integer, transaction_id: integer, sender_id: string, recipient_id: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, amount: float)

The code that creates the object is

```
transaction = Trans.new
transaction.find(id)
```

I'm calling this from within a method inside the model. I've tried the same by putting everything in a service and create a service object from within it. The result is the same.

Does this mean that the constructor/initialiser is not being called for some reason? I've not overwritten or changed the initialiser.

This is with Rails 4.

I'm trying to create an object so I can query the database.

Answer (score 0):

Although I've been working several hours on this, I figured out what was wrong shortly after I posted my question.

The object needs to be created like this:

```
trans = Trans.find(id)
```

instead of

```
trans = Trans.new

result = trans.find(id)
```

This seems counter-intuitive to me, but it works.

I hope this saves someone the several hours I lost!